# os x app couldn't load file in Resources folder

Tags: c++, macos

I'm trying to test library assimp on osx(Lion 10.7.5). But the Demo.app couldn't find model file located in Demo.app/Contents/Resources folder. It's strange that my old demo works fine though.
Here's the main code:

```
bool ImportModel(const string& pFile)
{
    Assimp::Importer importer;
    const aiScene* scene = importer.ReadFile(pFile, ...);
    if(!scene)
    {
        cout<<importer.GetErrorString()<<endl;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main(void)
{
    while(ImportModel("skin.xml"));
    return 0;
}
```

It keeps return: Unable to open file "skin.xml".
Here's the structure of Demo.app:

```
Contents
    Frameworks
    info.plist
    MacOS
        Demo
        libassimp.dylib
    Resources
        Demo.icns
        skin.xml -> the model file.
```

Any idea where could be wrong? Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation for assimp, `Assimp::Importer::ReadFile` takes a path as the first argument.  There doesn't appear to be (at least from the documentation), any specific support for defaulting the path to the `Resources` folder.

Chances are good that you're going to have to provide the full path to the file in order to read it correctly from those libraries, which means getting the main bundle's resource path, appending your model file name, and converting the final path to a c string (which will become a std::string). Alternatively, you could get the main bundle's resource path, convert it to a c string and append the `skin.xml` to that.

If you are using objective-c++, this is pretty simple:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource: @"skin" ofType: @"xml"];
// now get the c string from the path
const char *cPath =[path cStringUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

If you want to keep to C++ with foundation, it's a bit trickier because of the manual memory management and more extensive error checking (for above, you could get away with error checking only of `cPath`, since the Objective-C code will message `nil` without any problem).

Comment: Yes, i just found out, my previous "working" demo uses GLFW3, its glfwInit() does this bundle job. There's the problem. Thanks you for your detailed explanation :D